# How to open a different process of Mathematica in Windows when opening a file with explorer

Tags: front-end, windows

When I open any file with Mathematica in the Windows explorer, it just spaws a new window under current opened Mathematica process, using the same kernel. Is there a way to modify this default behavior and make it open a new process of Mathematica, just like what it would do under Linux?

Comment: I think you can search "M-WIN-LC.NB" in the regeditor of Windows system.

Comment: Put simply, no.

Comment: After opening the notebook but before evaluating it, select "Notebook Kernel" from the "Evaluation" menu and select a different Kernel.

Comment: @bcegkmqs23 I can't find this entry, can you tell me the exact path?

Comment: @Turgon It's `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\M-WIN-LC.NB.12.0.0.6237281\shell\open\command` in my system.